# Include Path - Relative path

Tags: php, include, relative-path

PHP-programmers!

I've got a problem with the Include-function in PHP.

I have a website which contains a left column-bar, and that column contains dynamic content which I get with the Include-function with a relative path, because absolute paths isn't available in the Include-function.

When I navigate to other files in other folders I get the error: include(folder/fileToBeIncluded.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/mywebsite/public_html/thissite/folder/subfolder/leftcolumn.php on line 3

How am I going to deal with that? I am totally lost, and I've been searching for Google and StackOverflow for about 10 minutes now.

Thank you!

Comment: What makes you think you can't include absolute paths in the include function?

Comment: Actually *read* the error. It tells you what the problem is. The file you want is not in the new folder, right? You'll need to change the include path for correctness. I suggest researching absolute paths, and using them.

Comment: "I've been searching for Google and StackOverflow for 10 minutes." Bravo. Great effort... please search harder next time and include some your own code to make it easier for us.

Answer (score 1):

Absolute paths are can be used with the `include` statement.

Try:

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/folder/fileToBeIncluded.php';
// or
include dirname(__FILE__) . '/../fileToBeIncluded.php'; // relative to the path of the file doing the include
```

At the very least, you can hardcode the path to be absolutely sure (until you move your site elsewhere):

```
include '/home/yoursite/public_html/folder/fileToInclude.php';
```

Please see [`include`](http://php.net/include) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest creating a dedicated "includes" folder? Something like:

`/home/mywebsite/includes`

in php.ini, you'd need to add:

`include_path = "/home/mywebsite/includes/"`

That way, all calls to include check from `/home/mywebsite/includes` for the file you need before looking for it relative to the location of the current page being process.